# Android Activities Stack and Dialog

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to understand some of the nuances of Activities.

The situation I'm in is as follows:

I have Activity A which will launch a new Activity, called Activity B.  However I want Activity B (and subsequent Activities (C, D, and E) which are launched from Activity B) to be in a "Dialog" (whether or actual or emulated) and a user can close out of at any point and return to Activity A in its previous state.

So essentially, can I launch Activity B/C/D/E in a self contained Dialog with its own "BackStack" history?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest file you can name the parent of your activity something like

```
<activity
    android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA" />
```

so if you enable in your code the up button or the back press it will take you to its parent.